# How to show nested form attributes in ruby on rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise and I built another table for the user information (username, firstname, lastname, address, etc.). What I want to do is when the user clicks on his profile settings (user model -> edit.html.erb view) to show the input fields for the attributes in the user_info table.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one  :user_info
```

and

```
class UserInfo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
```

my form seems like that:

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :username %>
    <%= f.text_field :username, :placeholder => "Enter username",

    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email, :placeholder => "Enter email" %>
```

and the controller

```
def edit
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user_info = current_user.user_info
end
```

Of course this doesn't work because username is not an attribute of the user but the user_info table. If I decide to print it, @user.user_info.username works, but what If I want to show and save specific nested form's fields ? Most SO replies mention how to render a partial with the nested form's attributes, but I want to be able to print one or two of them on demand, where I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same table User, and override Devise.

1. Migrate your informations to your User table

   `rails g migration add_username_to_users username:string`

   `rake db:migrate`
2. Generate views for Devise

   `rails g devise:views`
3. Add parameters to Devise

> In your application_controller.rb

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u| 
     u.permit(:username,
              :email, 
              :password,
              :password_confirmation,
              :remember_me) }
   end

   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) do |u| 
     u.permit(:username, 
              :email, 
              :password, 
              :password_confirmation, 
              :current_password) }
   end

  end
```

4. Modify Devise's views

> Add your fields in /views/registrations/edit.html.erb and /views/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= f.label :username %>
<%= f.input :username %>
```

Comment: It was the first option but I decided not to touch devise and create a separate table that I can do whatever I want. So finally, I want to display user.user_info.username and save it as a nested model attribute.